# What is a random sample (once again...)?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, descriptive-statistics

This is apparently asked many times but there is still something I do not understand. Taken from [Mathematical description of a random sample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47608/mathematical-description-of-a-random-sample):

> Mathematical description of a random sample: which one is it and why?
>
> 1. $X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega), ..., X_n(\omega)$, where $X_1, ..., X_n$ are different but i.i.d. random variables.
> 2. $X(\omega_1), X(\omega_2), ..., X(\omega_n)$, where $X$ is a (single) random variable.

I  would like to add:

3. $X_1(\omega_1), X_2(\omega_2), ..., X_n(\omega_n)$, where $X_1, ..., X_n$ are different but i.i.d. random variables.

Why not use 3.?

Comment: If you click on "edited * ago", you'll see the automatically generated summary "edited tags".  This inline tag edit was done using a [10k tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117624/259305).

Comment: Please refer to [this meta answer](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189) for the difference between the tags probit & probit theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research told me that nothing of the above is true; see for example the book of Dudley "Real analysis and Probability" (section 11.4). The empirical measure on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ is defined via a sequence of iid random variables $X_i$ defined on $\Omega^{\mathbb N}$, by the mapping
$$A\mapsto \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{X_i(\omega)}(A)\text{ for }\omega\in \Omega^{\mathbb N}.$$
The approximation property says that for almost all $\omega\in \Omega^{\mathbb N}$, the empirical measure converges weakly (or weakly-$*$ depending on your moods ;-) ) to $\mu$.